# where is my data? android studio

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

My goal is to start an `activity`, put some stuff on other `activity`, return back the object and use `onActivityResult` to add object to my `arraylist`.

The problem is theres nothing happening! no errors no new object in my `list`

Codes

**main/parentactivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    wish list =new wish();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,addList.class);
    mIntent.putExtra(KEY_TEXT, list);
    startActivityForResult(mIntent,KEY_CODE);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**child activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Intent data = new Intent(addList.this,MainActivity.class);
    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
    wish object = new wish("Title","stuff",99.99,R.drawable.insertphoto);
    extra.putSerializable(KEY_TEXT,object);
    data.putExtras(extra);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);

    finish();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == KEY_CODE){
                wish object = (wish) data.getSerializableExtra(KEY_TEXT);
                wishList.add(object);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're launching a new `MainActivity`, that's not going to work. And please edit your question to make a clear distinction classes your code belongs to. Now it look like you're overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` twice

Comment: sorry for the confusion, ive edited it. how do i go about fixing it.

Comment: Before you start modifying your array, try to log the result to make sure you getting anything from the activity

Comment: @jef ; My apologies, I thought you were launching a new instance of your `MainActivity`, but you're not

Comment: You should also handle errors in your onActivityResults method . that is if you want to see the error and try to debug it

Comment: `theres nothing happening! no errors no new object in my list`. Well first tell if onActivityResult() is called. You could display a Toast() there.

Comment: I thinkthat your `onActivityResult` should be inside `MainActivity`, not in the child activity

Comment: That would be a funny error ;-). But good catch then!

Comment: @MosheEdri i did as you suggested and found out i did indeed get data from the child activity. my codes were fine i just didnt have any to update the LIST so i assumed nothing was going on. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == KEY_CODE){
            wish object = (wish) data.getSerializableExtra(KEY_TEXT);

            if (object!=null) {
                wishList.add(object);
                mAdapter = new MyAdapter(wishList);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NULLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you create more layout managers? Surely one is enough for one view.